# Moving advanced search - Magento

Tags: magento

I am looking to move the advanced search, to the left-hand sidebar.

Is this possible to do?

Comment: Are you expecting an answer beyond "yes" or "no"? (If so, why?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very easy todo.

just change local.xml in your theme.

```
<default>
        <reference name="left">
            <block type="catalogsearch/advanced_form" name="catalogsearch_advanced_form" template="catalogsearch/advanced/form.phtml"/>
            <block type="core/html_calendar" name="html_calendar" as="html_calendar" template="page/js/calendar.phtml"/>
        </reference>
</default>
```

Then change CSS to fit this form into left sidebar.